# Attach a tag along with the values to a BigQuery table using the Data Catalog

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-data-catalog

I have multiple tables in BigQuery. I also have a tag template.
Is there a way to attach this tag template and fill the details programmatically with python to any table using the `google.cloud.datacatalog`?

```py
tag = datacatalog.Tag()
tag.template = 'my_project_id.my_tag_template'

data_sources_field = datacatalog.TagField()
data_sources_field.string_value = 'Test_data_source'
tag.fields['data_sources'] = data_sources_field

datacatalog_client.create_tag(parent=my_table_entry.name,
                              tag=tag)
```

I get the following error -

> PermissionDenied: 403 Permission denied on resource project my_project_id.my_tag_template.

The service account has 'project editor' role.

Comment: You mean create a tag template that fit your table description?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have multiple tables in the dataset. I have a generic tag template with keys like `data_source, rows_processed`. I am looking to attach this to each table along with their values like `data_source: abc, rows_processed: 47`. Please do advice if I my approach to using tag for this is incorrect, and if there is any other recommendation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the way the tagTemplate was called.

`tag.template = 'projects/<project-id>/locations/<location>/tagTemplates/<template_id>'`

Calling like above solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a tag template and attach a tag along with the values to the BigQuery table programmatically using Python API, refer to this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/quickstart-tagging#python).

If you are facing the same error (PermissionDenied : 403 Permission denied on resource project) as the OP, refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69701609/15747106) by the OP himself.

If you want to do the same through console, follow the below steps. For more information, refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/quickstart-tagging#console).

- Create a new tag template by navigating through Data Catalog -> Tag templates -> Create tag templates (Provide the “Template id”, “Location” and “Fields” based on your requirements and click create)
- To attach a tag to a table in your dataset, navigate through Data Catalog -> Search, enter your dataset/table name in the Search box, then click search. From the results, select your table which you want to attach a tag.
- After selecting the table, click “Attach Tags” and select your table name in “Choose what to tag”, then choose the tag template (which you have newly created) in “Choose the tag templates” and add values based on the display name and type as per your requirement in “Fill in tag values” and click save. The “Attach Tags” page will appear as shown below:

[image]

- You can check the created tag with values under the “Tags” on the table page in Data Catalog as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @vishal. I am aware of this procedure. My question is particularly how to accomplish this programmatically using python `google.cloud.catalog`.